# .first('li) select first item in the list not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hope you can help, this code is not working. It is selecting the next image ok, but if it is on the last image and there is no 'next image' then I want to select the first image in the 'li'. I've added an if condition: if (nextLi.value !=='')... but this doesn't seem to be working.

```
    function nextImg(){         
    $('#background').find('img').animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, function (){
        var nextLi = $('.sel').parent().parent().next('li').find('a');

        if (nextLi.value !=='') {
            var nextLiA = nextLi.attr('rel');
            $('#background').find('img').attr({'src':nextLiA});
            $('.sel').appendTo(nextLi); 
        } else {
            var nextLi = $('.sel').parent().parent().first('li').find('a');
            var nextLiA = nextLi.attr('rel');
            $('#background').find('img').attr({'src':nextLiA});
            $('.sel').appendTo(nextLi); 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup please

Answer (score 0):

You should use `length` instead, do:

```
if (!nextLi.length){
//do stuff
}
```

If the selection is empty `nextLi.length` will return 0 (i.e. `false`), so you add an `!`

Answer (score 0):

`nextLi` is a jQuery object. If you want to see if it contains any elements, i.e., if anything matched the selector(s) you used then just check its `.length` property:

```
if (nextLi.length > 0 ) {
```

Note also that the three lines inside the if block are the same as the last three lines of the else, so you can simplify your code as follows:

```
    if (nextLi.length === 0) {
        nextLi = $('.sel').parent().parent().first('li').find('a');
    }
    $('#background').find('img').attr({'src': nextLi.attr('rel') });
    $('.sel').appendTo(nextLi);
```

(I've removed the `nextLia` variable entirely since it was used in only one place - you can just use `nextLi.attr('rel')` directly when setting the `src` attribute.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It checks for the size of the `li` and if not found anything, selects the first.

```
function nextImg(){         
    $('#background').find('img').animate({'opacity': 0}, 500, function (){
        var li = $('.sel').parent().parent().next('li').find('a'); 

        if(li.length == 0) {
           //if there is not last item  
           li = $('.sel').parent().parent().first('li').find('a'); //get the first item
        } 
        var liA = li.attr('rel');
        $('#background').find('img').attr({'src':liA});
        $('.sel').appendTo(li); 

    });
}
```